# Rails routes - show action as root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm looking to make a show action of one of my controllers the root.
I can easily do this:

```
map.root :controller => 'articles', :action => 'index'
```

When I go to localhost:3000/ it lists all the articles - that's great!
What I want to achieve, though, is a URL like this

```
localhost:3000/1
```

To display an article with the id 1.
Changing the route the the following would be what I'd think I have to do:

```
map.root :controller => 'articles', :action => 'show'
```

But it does not seem to work. Instead - it looks for a controller called `1` - which does not exist.

How would I go about doing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this in `routes.rb`

`map.connect ':id', :controller => 'articles', :action => 'show'`

You'll want to make sure this is a **low priority** route because of how general it is. I.e., put it toward the bottom of your `routes.rb` file but above this section (if you haven't deleted it already):

```
# low-priorty article show route
map.connect ':id', :controller => 'articles', :action => 'show'

# Install the default routes as the lowest priority.
# Note: These default routes make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests. You should
# consider removing or commenting them out if you're using named routes and resources.
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

Comment: thank you. You were the first to give an answer so you're getting the credit. Thanks for the extra explanation in your edit.

Answer (score 5):

A root route define only one route. Not several. You can define another route

`map.connect '/:id', :controller => 'articles', :action => 'show'`

If you want this style of route, maybe a resources (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html#M000522) is great for you.

Comment: works, but now none of my other controllers are accessible. Any way around that?

Comment: and to answer my own question - make sure that this line of code is below any other ones you want to have priority. In routes.rb the higher the route in the list the higher the priority.

Comment: just a note, shingara; you don't need the `/` before `:id` :)

Comment: yes it's not mandatory, but I found that much simplest to understand the real matching route

Answer (score 3):

In Rails 3 there is no map method available in routes. Instead use something like this:

```
match ':id', :controller => 'articles', :action => 'show'
```

And remember to put it below the routes that should take precedence.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
resource :articles, :path => '/'
```

with this all of your article will be directly under root